# Magento2 : Having issue with product add to cart jmeter

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart, jmeter

I am using `Magento2.2.5` and using `benchmark_2015.jmx`, Facing issue when test for logged in customer and adding product to cart, Cart shows empty.

It's default magento benchmark_2015 script, stored in the installation folder at setup/performance-toolkit/benchmark_2015.jmx
Request where form key is extracted : http://prntscr.com/mty0su
Login request : http://prntscr.com/mty19u
Add to cart request : http://prntscr.com/mty00o
Let me know if you need more details

https://image.prntscr.com/image/2QJvTGhnS_6ROx0aM7-goA.png

https://image.prntscr.com/image/Hv3aM1XIRp6Y_VmJjub5QA.png

https://image.prntscr.com/image/Yz6glTNgTpONPv0LWChj2A.png

Comment: Could you show your test plan, login, adding, cart requests and responces? 
It's difficult to say what is wrong without any information.

Comment: @VadimYangunaev, I updated the question.